# Exclude columns by name

Tags: r

This is my sample data frame

```
DF
x.a.p   y.b.l    x.a.pl    y.b.c   z.d.ce
```

Those are numeric columns. How can i exclude from `DF` columns which names end with `.p` and `.l`
I tried to find these columns with `grep` and then `subset` but it didn't work. 
Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep`

```
DF[!grepl('\\.(p|l)$', names(DF))]
```

#### data

```
DF <- data.frame(x.a.p= 1:5, y.b.l= 6:10, x.a.pl= 11:15, 
             y.b.c= 16:20, z.d.ce = 21:25)
```

Comment: @fdetsch  Yes, you are right.  Sorry, a mistake.  I was testing it and was kind of so embarrassed to find that `grepl` not found

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strsplit` with argument `fixed = TRUE` such that the splitting string is not considered as a regular expression.

```
names_df <- c("x.a.p", "y.b.l", "x.a.pl", "y.b.c", "z.d.ce")

vapply(names_df, function(x) {
  s <- strsplit(x, ".", fixed = TRUE)[[1]][3] 
  s == "l" || s == "p"
  }, TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help!